# Image cannot be zoomed in out when loaded into UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, uiwebview, loaddata

I have an image encoded in BASE64 which I retrieve from a server and than load into a UIWebView
with :

```
[webViewer loadData:[NSData decodeBase64ForString:imageData] MIMEType:@"image" textEncodingName:@"ASCII" baseURL:nil];
```

The image loads fine but when the image is bigger than my webviewer, the user cannot zoom in and
out by pinching the iphone like in all other UIWebView documents.

The user can move the picture around to see the whole picture but since they cannot zoom out, they 
cannot see the whole picture in the size of the UIWebView frame.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

add this to your webview HTML, basically use an image tag and place the meta tag in the HTML String

```
NSString * header = @"<meta name='viewport' content='width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=2.0; user-scalable=1;'/>"
NSString * html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>%@<img src='%@'/></html>",header,imageData]
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Aaron thanks for the advice but there is no HTML. In this case loadData is loading the raw image data into a UIWebView.

Comment: By using `content='width=device-width; maximum-scale=3.0; user-scalable=1;'` I achieved not only automatic width adjustment for whatever my webview's width is set to, but it also automatically zooms in to optimal size, as if one had double-tapped onto the view.